# Trouble getting a connection from outside with Windows sockets

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

I am reading a Python tutorial and using the Visual Studio 2015 interactive window. The tutorial uses print(b,end=','). But when I type the exact example I always get an error. Here is one such example:

```
>>> a, b = 0, 1
>>> while b < 1000:
...     print(b, end=',')
...     a, b = b, a+b
...
1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,
```

Here is what happens using VS2015:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(b, end=',')
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I have searched for this problem but nothing mentions it. Then I tried end="," but I get the same error.

Could it be that the tutorial is wrong or that VS is not a perfect Python interpreter?

Comment: Visual Studio itself (and Python Tools for Visual Studio) does not include any Python interpreter. It uses the one(s) that you have installed on your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tutorial is showing Python 3 `print` syntax, and the error message you are receiving is the message displayed when you attempt to use that syntax under Python 2.x or earlier:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("foo", end=', ')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("foo", end=', ')
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You should figure out how in install/run Python 3 in your environment (or find a Python 2.x tutorial, of which there are many).

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove the interpreter I have and install a new one.

Comment: BTW, I notice I had a title that I used to start a different question. Apparently I forgot to change the heading.